# RegCreateKeyEx succeeding, but no key added

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I am trying to get into C++ programming on Windows for reverse engineering purpose, and I am stuck trying to had a Windows registry key. The functions RegCreateKey and RegSetValueEx are returning ERROR_SUCCESS, but the key is missing when checking the registry.

Here is the code:

```cpp
void AddRunKey() {
    wchar_t subkey[512];
    wchar_t cmd[512];
    wcscpy_s(subkey, L"Test");
    wcscpy_s(cmd, L"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe");

    HKEY runKey;
    long res;
    res = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurentVersion\\Run", 0, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &runKey, NULL);
    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "fail\n";
    }


    res = RegSetValueEx(runKey, subkey, 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (BYTE*)cmd, wcslen(cmd) + 1);
    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "fail\n";
    }

    RegCloseKey(runKey);

}
    
int _tmain() {
    AddRunKey();
          
}
```

I compiled it on Visual Studio, release mode, 64 bits on a Windows 10 - 64 bits virtual machine. No errors are returned when running the code.

When opening the Windows registry editor, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, the key cannot be found

What is causing this behavior ? How can I fix it ?

EDIT (updated the key path): RegCloseKey returns 0

Comment: Return value of reg close key is?

Comment: The return value of RegCloseKey is 0
The full path is "Ordinateur\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

Comment: In the posted code, you are not flushing what you write to `std::cout`. You may want to add a `std::flush` or `std::endl`. However, flushing should not be necessary if your program indeed exits immediately after your call to `AddRunKey` (which your posted code suggests).

Comment: In the registry editor of Windows 7, you may have to press F5 (refresh) in order for changes to become visible, if the registry editor was already open before the changes were made. I'm not sure if this is also necessary in Windows 10.

Comment: An obvious error is that the last argument of `RegSetValueEx` is in bytes, so it should be `(wcslen(cmd) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)`

Comment: You are creating a value under `Run` key, not a key (even though you misleadingly refer to it as `subkey`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several mistakes in your code.

You need to escape the `\` characters in your file path.

You misspelled `CurentVersion` in the key path. It needs to be `CurrentVersion` instead.

You are calling `RegSetValueEx()` and `RegCloseKey()` unconditionally whether `RegCreateKeyEx()` succeeds or fails.

You need to specify the value size in the last parameter of `RegSetValueEx()` in *bytes* and not in *characters*.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void AddRunKey() {
    wchar_t subkey[512];
    wchar_t cmd[512];
    wcscpy_s(subkey, L"Test");
    wcscpy_s(cmd, L"%windir%\\system32\\cmd.exe");

    HKEY runKey;
    long res = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, NULL, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &runKey, NULL);
    if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "fail\n";
    }
    else
    {
        res = RegSetValueEx(runKey, subkey, 0, REG_EXPAND_SZ, (BYTE*)cmd, (wcslen(cmd) + 1) * sizeof(cmd[0]));
        if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            std::cout << "fail\n";
        }

        RegCloseKey(runKey);
    }
}
    
int _tmain() {
    AddRunKey();
}
```